# Not buffered http.ResponseWritter in Golang

Tags: http, stream, go, flush

I'm writing a simple web app in Go and I want my responses to be streamed to the client (i.e. not buffered and sent in blocks once the request is fully processed) :

```
func handle(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
  fmt.Fprintf(res, "sending first line of data")
  sleep(10) //not real code
  fmt.Fprintf(res, "sending second line of data")
}
```

From the client point of view, the two lines will be sent at the same time. Any suggestions are appreciated :)

#### Edit after @dystroy answer

It's possible to flush after each write I personally make, but in my use case it's not enough:

```
cmd := exec.Command("a long command that outputs lots of lines")
cmd.Stdout = res //where res is a http.ResponseWritter
cmd.Stderr = res
err := cmd.Run()
```

I want the output of my `cmd` to be flushed as well. Anyway to "autoflush" the ResponseWritter ?

#### Solution

I found help on golang's mailing list. There is 2 way to achieve this: using [hijacker](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_Hijacker) that allow to take over the underlying TCP connection of HTTP, or piping the stdout and stderr of the command in a go routine that will write and flush :

```
pipeReader, pipeWriter := io.Pipe()
cmd.Stdout = pipeWriter
cmd.Stderr = pipeWriter
go writeCmdOutput(res, pipeReader)
err := cmd.Run()
pipeWriter.Close()

//---------------------
func writeCmdOutput(res http.ResponseWriter, pipeReader *io.PipeReader) {
  buffer := make([]byte, BUF_LEN)
  for {
    n, err := pipeReader.Read(buffer)
    if err != nil {
      pipeReader.Close()
      break
    }

    data := buffer[0:n]
    res.Write(data)
    if f, ok := res.(http.Flusher); ok {
      f.Flush()
    }
    //reset buffer
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
      buffer[i] = 0
    }
  } 
}
```

#### Last update

Even nicer: http://play.golang.org/p/PpbPyXbtEs

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As implied in [the documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Flusher), some `ResponseWriter` may implement the `Flusher` interface.

This means you can do something like this :

```
func handle(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
  fmt.Fprintf(res, "sending first line of data")
  if f, ok := res.(http.Flusher); ok {
     f.Flush()
  } else {
     log.Println("Damn, no flush");
  }
  sleep(10) //not real code
  fmt.Fprintf(res, "sending second line of data")
}
```

Be careful that buffering can occur in many other places in the network or client side.

Comment: Thx for your answer, I came across this but seemed too "hakish" at first sight. I updated my question

Comment: Updated my answer again with solutions to buffer `exec.Cmd` stdout. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I've misunderstood your question, but would something like the below do the trick?

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    body := make([]byte, int(r.ContentLength))
    b := bytes.NewBuffer(body)
    if _, err := b.ReadFrom(r.Body); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s", err)
    }
    if _, err := b.WriteTo(w); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s", err)
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

`$ curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://localhost:8080`

returns:

> > param1=value1&param2=value2

You could always append whatever data you wanted to `body`, or read more bytes into the buffer from elsewhere before writing it all out again.

Answer (score 1):

In Go 1.20 or later, use [ResponseController.Flush](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ResponseController.Flush) to flush the response.

```
func handle(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    rc := http.NewResponseController(res)
    fmt.Fprintf(res, "sending first line of data")
    if err := rc.Flush(); err != nil {
        // Handle error in some way.
        log.Println("Oops, no flush")
    }
    sleep(10) //not real code
    fmt.Fprintf(res, "sending second line of data")
}
```