# How do I read a streaming response body using Golang's net/http package?

Tags: http, go, http-streaming

I am trying to connect to an endpoint that does http streaming of json data.  I was wondering how to perform a basic request using Go's net/http package and read the response as it comes in.  Currently, I am only able to read the response when the connection closes.

```
resp, err := http.Get("localhost:8080/stream")
if err != nil {
    ...
}
...
// perform work while connected and getting data
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

-RC

Comment: Did you see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292113/not-buffered-http-responsewritter-in-golang) and does it help?

Comment: That code will operate on a stream. If you're not getting it when you expect, it's because of how the server is sending it.  I've parsed many GBs of responses with this model.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The way to do streaming JSON parsing is with a Decoder:

```
json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&yourStuff)
```

For a streaming API where it's a bunch of objects coming back (a la Twitter), that should stream great with this model and the built-in encoding/json API. But if it's a large response where you have an object that's got a giant array with 10MB of stuff, you probably need to write your own Decoder to pull those inner pieces out and return them. I'm running into that problem with a library I've written.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I managed to get it working by creating a bufio.Reader and calling ReadBytes() on the resp.Body.

Comment: Eve, where documentation about max 10MB? i need information

Comment: It's not a max, it's just the way the parser works, objects at a time.

Comment: Is there a way to listen for when the response has finished being written?

Answer (score 48):

The answer provided by Eve Freeman is the correct way to read json data.  For reading any type of data, you can use the method below:

```
resp, err := http.Get("http://localhost:3000/stream")
...

reader := bufio.NewReader(resp.Body)
for {
    line, err := reader.ReadBytes('\n')
    ...

    log.Println(string(line))
}
```

Comment: But how does one detect EOF on that []byte?

Comment: EOF is returned with err

Comment: now using these chunks/lines how can I directly write it to file. Means how write using stream not whole as file. ?